# How do I use 'Match' to find the first cell at the end of a column in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

**Excel based:**

I am using {=MATCH(0,INT(A:A),0)} in Excel to select the first row after the last filled cell in Column A (note the last value is either followed by a 0 or a blank cell, which is why I use INT()). This works just fine, however I have trouble replicating it in VBA.

This will be a very simple fix, but I can't quite get it! Thanks in advance

**My attempt in VBA:**

```
Application.Match(0, Int(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormulaArray), 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("MATCH(0,INT(A:A),0)")
```

Don't use the `Application.Evaluate` form unless you specifically want the formula to be evaluated in the context of whichever sheet happens to be active.

Comment: This is what I was after thanks Tim. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a simple fix to replicate your formula in VBA because it is an array formula in Excel, and you'd have to loop through each cell because of the `INT` function.

(Not tested) To find the last cell in a column in VBA, do something like:

```
set myCell = Cells(Rows.Count,1).end(xlup)
```

and to find the first empty cell:

```
set myCell = Cells(Rows.Count,1).end(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

Of course, as in your VBA attempt, qualifying the worksheet is appropriate and preferred

```
With worksheets("Sheet1")
   set myCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).end(xlup)
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ron, but these do not account for when there are values of 0 in the column (which I want to ignore)

Comment: @jwem93 I'd just check the value of that cell for zero.